# Append class to dynamically added div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
$("#cardd10").prepend("<div id='newdivid'>");
$("#newdivid").addClass('card front hoverimage');
```

I added a class to a dynamically added div.  I checked through inspect element in browser, class `card front hoverimage` is added - but the style is not added from css.

i want to get style="perspective: 454px; position: relative;" from that css. but the style is not loading through javscript.if i add through the html, i am able to get the style. but if i try with javascript, style is not loading

Comment: Unable to replicate, the code you've shown works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/t9qsne3o/. If styles are not being added then check in the DOM inspector to ensure that the rules are specific enough to override any pre-existing ones you've set

Comment: We can't know from just that code what is happening? Also, do you close the `div` you're adding anywhere?

Comment: Code works fine for me, can you be more specific?

Comment: add a static div having same class, see if you have style available to browser, as this should work.

Comment: i want to get  style="perspective: 454px; position: relative;" from that css. but the style is not loading through javscript.if i add through the html, i am able to get the style. but if i try with javascript, style is not loading

Comment: Does your `newdivid` have any content?  In the code you've provided, you won't be able to see the new div simply because it's empty.

Comment: can you replicate your issue on jsfiddle or on stackoverflow snippet?

Comment: @PrinuPhilip  create a fiddle example of your problem so that we can see and rectify it

Answer (score 2):

you have to add closing `</div>` and then it will work:-

```js
$("#cardd10").prepend("<div id='newdivid'>def</div>");
$("#newdivid").addClass('card front hoverimage');
```

```css
.card{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "cardd10"></div>
```

Comment: hitting the bulls eye +1 from me.

Comment: i just showed the id only...its closing the div in my code..but the css is not adding to that div.

Comment: @PrinuPhilip  it's hard to rectify your problem until you will reproduce it and give us a link for that. because we are not able to produce it.

Comment: Although admittedly this is better practice, jQuery is smart enough to fill the closing tag for you when appending to the DOM. This will not affect the OPs issue

Comment: So in that case why answer until the problem has been identified?